# ! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands

Tags: packages, document-classes

I tried different versions of WinEdt and MiKTeX but every time I run the code find this error:

**! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H   for immediate help.  ...

  l.450     \documentclass{
                         ltxdoc}**

And as a result it could not create PDF file. I am a beginner and guess it should be about packages used there.

Thanks for comments, I am 100% sure that there is only one `\documentclass` and here is the list of packages used:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

%
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
% IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
% requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
% normal IEEE
\usepackage{cite}
\fi


\newcommand\MYhyperrefoptions{bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,
pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels=true,
colorlinks=true,linkcolor={black},citecolor={black},urlcolor={black},
pdftitle={Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Computer Society Journals},%   <!CHANGE!
pdfsubject={Typesetting},%<!CHANGE!
pdfauthor={Michael D. Shell},%<!CHANGE!
pdfkeywords={Computer Society, IEEEtran, journal, LaTeX, paper,
         template}}%<^!CHANGE!
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{program}
\usepackage{keywords}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the most common reason for getting the error about two `\documentclass` commands is that you have two `\documentclass` commands and the fix is to remove one of them. If you show no code how can anyone help?

Comment: actually `ltxdoc` is only used for documenting packages, never in real documents, have you gone `\input{somepackage.dtx}` in your main file?

Comment: the posted code causes no error (other than a missing package keywords} I can only guess that you have saved some file `abc.dtx` as `abc.sty` (which would cause that error)

Comment: unrelated to the error but do not load kantlipsum in a real document and don't load epsfig in a document written since 1994

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the MWE never showed the bit of code that caused the error.

Comment: @samcarter: What about some lenience? Please don't scare new users.

Comment: @samcarter seems a bit harsh, posted enough for me to correctly guess the cause.

Comment: @Schweinebacke @ DavidCharlisle OK, maybe I overreacted. I retracted by close vote, but MWE which do not show the problem are to me the one red rag of this site. They waste the time of all the great people here who try to help the OPs.

Comment: @samcarter The OP (in the end) posted a complete smallish document, if he'd known the problem was in another file altogether then he wouldn't have needed to ask the question.

Answer (score 5):

You will get this error if you rename a documented class or package file `abc.dtx` as `abc.sty`.  The dtx file is a *document* with its own `\documentclass` for typesetting the package documentation. The package file may be extracted from that (usually by running tex on `abc.ins`)

Comment: For future readers: I just got this error when I saved the TeX file as a .aux (accidentally) and did a save-as to a .tex file without removing the bad .aux file.

Comment: Likewise: I had named a document file keyval.tex, and when I tried to compile another document in the same folder using `standalone` class, I got this error. (Standalone uses the keyval package). Both moving the second document to its own folder, and renaming keyval.tex to something else, allowed compilation to complete.

Comment: Don't rename keyval.tex to xkeyval.tex, either!